# Podio POST request returns unauthorized

Tags: podio, unauthorized

I'm working on a Podio integration as a Slack bot.
I'm starting to use it just for use for my company to test it, then I could share it with everybody.
I've used the podio-js platform with Node JS, and started locally with a "web app" by starting from this example: https://github.com/podio/podio-js/tree/master/examples/password_auth

I need to do a post request, so I maintained all the code of the example in order  to log in with user and password. The original code worked, then I changed the code to make a post request, in particular I change the lines of index.js into this:

```js
router.get('/user', function(req, res) {
 
  podio.isAuthenticated().then(function () {
   var requestData = { "title": "sample_value" };
    return podio.request('POST', '/item/app/15490175', requestData);
  })
  .then(function(responseData) {
    res.render('user', { data: responseData });
  })
  .catch(function () {
    res.send(401);
  });
});
```

But in the end is giving a "Unauthorized" response. 
It seems like the password auth doesn't let to make POST request to add new items! Is that possible?
I've already read all the documentation but I'm not able to explain why and how I can solve this.
Regards

Comment: Can you clarify what error message you get from Podio API?

For Podio API it doesn't matter if request is GET or POST, authentication part works exactly the same. So, it seems that there is some other error here.

Comment: The error message is just "Unauthorized". The PODIO api is a bit confusing... Should definitely be clear like Airtable https://airtable.com/api .. It's too hard to understand why there are 4 differnet way to authenticate on Podio.

Comment: Are you sure the error you are seeing is not coming from ` res.send(401);` line in your snippet? I'm actually interested in Podio error?

Comment: Will work on it again in two days, I'll reply you as soon as possible. What I can tell you is that I simply worked on this example from your node js library and changed it in order to make a simple POST request.. It seems that pass auth don't let make post requests, is that possible? Will indagate on it and will get back to you soon in case you might not understand where the problem is. Thanks!